# Implementing FreezeFrame.js Correctly

Tags: jquery

I have been at this for hours, trying to implement freezeframe.js on a simple webpage.

Freezframe.js github:
https://github.com/ctrl-freaks/freezeframe.js

My simple page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://travisbklein.com/freezeframe.js-master/build/css/freezeframe_styles.min.css">

</head><body><img src="http://travisbklein.com/animatedgif.gif" class="myclass">

<script src="http://travisbklein.com/freezeframe.js-master/src/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="http://travisbklein.com/freezeframe.js-master/build/js/freezeframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>


<script>
   var ff = new freezeframe({
  'selector': 'myclass',
  'animation_play_duration': 3000,
  'non_touch_device_trigger_event': 'hover'
})
</script>


</body></html>
```

I think the problem is the Selector I am using is the class I called the image in my html file which is MYCLASS, and maybe that's wrong I think?

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Could you describe the results you want, as well as the results you're getting, to help readers better understand your problem?

Comment: I can't even figure out how to post my html page

Comment: Formatting help can provide information for how to include code snippets, or other formatting issues: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: whew, lol finally got it up there.  I'd love to be able to only play my gif file on hover action.

Comment: I solved it finally, with some help.  My foot script was wrong, it needs the "." before the class name.
here is my updated script which works:
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    first = new freezeframe('.mypage-post-image-file').freeze();

  })
</script> 

where my class is "mypage-post-image-file"

Answer (score 0):

I solved it finally, with some help.  My foot script was wrong, it needs the "." before the class name.
here is my updated script which works:

```
> <script type="text/javascript">   $(function() {
>     first = new freezeframe('.mypage-post-image-file').freeze();
> 
>   }) </script>
```

where my class is "mypage-post-image-file"